# Swift repeat while statement with readLine

Tags: swift, xcode

I can't see why the compiler doesn't allow me to use this pretty simple assignment as my while loop  condition:

```
// Get user's input
repeat {
    // displays possible actions
    print("Select one of the following actions (by writing the text within the parenthesis):\n")
    for action in actions {
        print(action.description+" ("+action.name+")\n")
    }
} while !(let chosen_action = readLine())
```

Also, it creates a bug in Xcode (code appears all grey, like it was not recognised anymore).

Thank you

Comment: How does it not work? `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers`

Comment: Sorry I was in a rush. I'll edit it a little later.

Comment: Your code does not compile because in Swift (contrary to C), the assignment statement does not return a value. But what do you *expect* to happen? What is the purpose of the loop? Because `readLine()` returns nil only on end-of-file, and then you cannot continue anyway.

Comment: @Martin_r Ok I tought if the user pressed "enter" without any input or if anyhow I didn't get any value the assignment would return nil

Comment: I meant "would return *false"

Comment: In that case `readLine` returns an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's not valid Swift code
2. Even if it runs, what if I choose an item that's not on your action list?

---

Try this:

```
struct Action {
    var name: String
    var description: String
}
let actions = [
    Action(name: "a", description: "Action A"),
    Action(name: "b", description: "Action B")
]

var chosen_action: Action?
repeat {
    print("Select one of the following actions (by writing the text within the parenthesis):")
    for action in actions {
        print(action.description+" ("+action.name+")")
    }

    let actionName = readLine()
    chosen_action = actions.first { $0.name == actionName }
} while chosen_action == nil
```